# JS RegExp classname first element

Tags: javascript, regex, classname

I'm currently trying to find the classname of the first "element" of an DOM-String.
It's NO DOM at all, it's just the string of a particular DOM element.

**Example:**

```
var test = '<div class="a_classname a_2nd_classname">[OTHER DOM ELEMENTS HERE]</div>';
```

My problem is that I don't know the content of the var (it's an ajax response) before it finished loading. So it has to be absolutely dynamic via regexp and I need the whole classname of the first element in that var.

I've googled around but nothing fixed my problem.

Any advise is welcome :)

thx a lot

Comment: Especially if it's an ajax response, it shouldn't be hard to *make* it a DOM. Just get the `responseXML` instead of the `responseText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery if you're using it in your code

```
$('<div class="a_classname a_2nd_classname"><a class="foo">bar<a>[OTHER DOM ELEMENTS HERE]</div>').attr("class")
```

Or use DomParser

```
var xmlString = '<div class="a_classname a_2nd_classname"><a class="foo">bar<a>[OTHER DOM ELEMENTS HERE]</div>';
var parser = new DOMParser() ;
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
doc.firstChild.className // => "a_classname a_2nd_classname"
```

Comment: Hi, oh the DOMParser looks nice ... but isn't it to heavy for such a thing like the classname?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure, test contains html:

   if (/^<.+>$/.test(test))
2. then, call $() upon it:

   var tempHtml = $(test);
3. It will parse the markup which you can query either by jQuery or directly:

   var firstElementClassNames = tempHtml[0].className.split(' ');

Comment: Hi Andrevsinky, sorry, I forgot to say that I don't want use jQuery.
But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regular expression will capture the class name of the first `div` tag in the string. The expression does need the options `s` and `m` for match all lines and dot matches new line characters.

`\A.*?<div\b(?=\s)(?=(?:(?![^>])'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|.)*\sclass="([^"]*)")`

[image]

If you don't know the first element name with a class attribute, then you could modify the expression by replacing the tag name with `\w+`. Capture group 0 will contain the tag name and the opening bracket:

``\A.*?<\w+\b(?=\s)(?=(?:(?![^>])'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|.)*\sclass="([^"]*)")`

## Javascript Example

**Input sample text**

```
<div class="a_classname a_2nd_classname">[OTHER DOM ELEMENTS HERE]</div>
```

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /\A.*?<div\b(?=\s)(?=(?:(?![^>])'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|.)*\sclass="([^"]*)")/;
  var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  var results = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
    results[i] = matches;
    for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
      alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
    }
    i++;
  }
</script>
```

**Matches**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a_classname a_2nd_classname
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi,this looks awesome. I'll try it as soon as possible (currently not on the computer) ... THX a lot